# 403.7 - Client Certificate Dialog Not Prompted

Tags: windows, security

Here is my scenario:

Server: Windows 2K3 SP2 x86 IIS6, with a Web Site with SSL, requiring client certificates.
The server certificate was issued by a CA (AD Directory Services).

Client: IE8 with a client certificate installed in the personal store (current user),which was issued by the some CA. The chain CA certificates are installer on the client in the Trusted Root Certificatation Authoritie.

When the client hits the web site, it is getting 
HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden: SSL client certificate is required.

The browser is not prompting to choose the certificate to use. I already tried in different client machines, and we havre the same behaviour.

The SSLDiag on the server reports everytinhg is ok. I already research the obvious solution from KB articles from MS.

I already did this kind of scenario multiple times, and always worked, but it seems there is something with this server that I am not figuring out.

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact problem, everything was configured correctly but the dialog was never prompted. Fortunately the solution was easy, the IIS needed to be restarted. We spent many hours troubleshooting before testing that solution...